# Getting around using a SQL inner-join to connect a second select statement

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join

I have two different reference columns from one table that join to a single matching column in another table. Bringing in several columns from this joined table the only way I can figure out how to pull the same columns in twice with two different reference columns, is to use an inner-join on a second select statement. Using this in conjunction with all of the other columns and joins, beyond what you see below, makes the data pull too slow to pull for the amount of data I am pulling. Is there away I can do the below with out the second select statement?

```
Select *
From
    (Select Distinct
         P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_PCK_LOC_ID,
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_NM "Pick Name",
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_CITY_AD "Pick City",
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_ST_AD "Pick State",
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_ZIP_AD "Pick Zip",
         P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID
     From  
         P1736.LL_SHP_LEG
     Left Outer Join 
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL On P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_PCK_LOC_ID = P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_RFNC_ID
     Where 
         (P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_LD_EXTRT_ID > '43000000')) Q1
Inner Join
    (Select Distinct
         P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID,
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_NM "Drop Name",
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_CITY_AD "Drop City",
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_ST_AD "Drop State",
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_ZIP_AD "Drop Zip"
     From 
         P1736.LL_SHP_LEG
     Left Outer Join 
         P1736.LL_LOC_DTL On P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID = P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_RFNC_ID
     Where 
         (P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_LD_EXTRT_ID > '43000000')) Q2 On Q1.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID = Q2.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try OR in join condition? since i do not have data, i am unable to verify, please let me know if the below query helps

```
Select Distinct
P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_PCK_LOC_ID,
P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_NM "Pick Name",
P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_CITY_AD "Pick City",
P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_ST_AD "Pick State",
P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_ZIP_AD "Pick Zip",
P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID
From P1736.LL_SHP_LEG
Left Outer Join P1736.LL_LOC_DTL
On ((P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_PCK_LOC_ID = P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_RFNC_ID) 
     OR (P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_SHP_LEG_DROP_LOC_ID = P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_RFNC_ID))
Where (P1736.LL_SHP_LEG.LL_LD_EXTRT_ID > '43000000')
```

Comment: Thank you Abhilash, but like using the On And, it will only connect on the PCK_LOC_ID. Rather than both the PCK and DROP references.

Comment: Did you use OR or AND?

Comment: I used or and added the 4 location columns, changing their names to drop rather than pick. That's the tricky part, I need to pull in the same columns twice once off each reference. P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_NM "Pick Name", P1736.LL_LOC_DTL.LL_LOC_NM "Drop Name"...